# How to make a dispatch before form Submit in Redux Forms ? (using TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, redux, form-submit, redux-form

Here is my submit function in a separated file what i wanna do is to make dispatch to change logged in state to true before redirection

```
import React from "react";
import { SubmissionError } from "redux-form";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import ax from "axios";

function submit(values: any) {
  return ax.get("./UserCredentials.json").then(res => {
    console.log(values);
    if (!values.username || !values.password) {
      throw new SubmissionError({
        username: "Please enter your credentials",
        _error: "Login failed!"
      });
    } else if (res.data[0].username !== values.username) {
      throw new SubmissionError({
        username: "User does not exist",
        _error: "Login failed!"
      });
    } else if (res.data[0].password !== values.password) {
      throw new SubmissionError({
        password: "Wrong password",
        _error: "Login failed!"
      });
    } else {
      //console.log("redirect to profile");
      //props.dispatch(login());     // i need to make dispatch here
      return <Redirect to="/profile" />;
    }
  });
}

export default submit;
```

i cann't figure out how to do it the right way

Comment: are you using redux-thunks? this whole process should be an action

Comment: no i don't use it, i don't need it actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your function asynchronous like this :

```
import React from "react";
import { SubmissionError } from "redux-form";
import ax from "axios";

async function submit(values) {
  const result = await ax.get("./UserCredentials.json").then(res => {
    console.log(values);
    if (!values.username || !values.password) {
      throw new SubmissionError({
        username: "Please enter your credentials",
        _error: "Login failed!"
      });
    } else if (res.data[0].username !== values.username) {
      throw new SubmissionError({
        username: "User does not exist",
        _error: "Login failed!"
      });
    } else if (res.data[0].password !== values.password) {
      throw new SubmissionError({
        password: "Wrong password",
        _error: "Login failed!"
      });
    }
  });

  if (result) {
    // do your stuff
  }
}

export default submit;
```

Comment: thank you @Sephyre but what i need is to dispatch an action not waiting for the result of axios call, anyway i got the solution after searching the OnSubmit function has another argument for dispatch as a second argument :) like this

const submit = (values: any, dispatch: Dispatch) => { 
     //stuff here.....
}